# what does an non parameterized constructor of thread do and how can its sleep method be called before starting it

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class queue
{
    int q[],f=0,r=0,size;
    void insert(int n ){
        Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);
        q=new int[10];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            System.out.println("\n enter"+i+"element");
            int ele= in.nextInt();
            if(r+1>10){
                System.out.println("\n queue is full\n lost packets"+ele);
                break;
            }
            else{
                r++;
                q[i]=ele;
            }
        }
    }

    void delete(){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Thread t = new Thread();
        if(r==0)
            System.out.println("\n Queue is empty");
         else{
             for(int i=f;i<r;i++){
                 try{
                      t.sleep(1000);
                  }
                  catch(Exception e){}
                  System.out.println("\n leaked packet"+q[i]);
                   f++;
                  }
              }
              System.out.println();
         }
 }

            public class Leaky extends Thread {

                public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                    queue q = new queue();
                    Scanner src = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("enter the packet to be sent");
                    int size = src.nextInt();
                    q.insert(size);
                    q.delete();

                }

            }
```

This is code which is to demonstrate leaky bucket algorithm in networks.
Here, how can the thread's sleep method be called before it is started? Also this code gives output on every second. How is this possible when threads run parallel with main thread? How can that affect the output(ie introduce a delay of 1second)? Where is non parameterized constructor used, how can the run method be called internally by jvm when we don't pass the class which either extends Thread class or implements Runnable interface as a parameter?

Answer (score 2):

> Here,how can the thread's sleep method be called before it is started.

`Thread.sleep` is a `static` method, which `Causes the currently executing thread to sleep`. i.e. this code causes the main thread to sleep. It doesn't matter if you call it with `t.sleep(1000)` or `Thread.sleep(1000)` - the result is the same.

The `Thread` instance created in this code (by `Thread t = new Thread()`) is never started, so there is only one thread running.

> Also this code gives output on every second. How is this possible when threads run parallel with main thread.How can that affect the output(ie introduce a delay of 1second).

As I said, there is only one thread running here - the main thread. `Thread.sleep(1000)` causes that thread to sleep for 1 second.

> Where is non parameterized constructor used,how can the run method be called internally by jvm when we don't pass the class which either extends Thread class or implements Runnable interface as a parameter

If you add a call to `t.start()` in this code, it will execute `Thread`'s `run()` method, which will do nothing, as the Javadoc says - `If this thread was constructed using a separate Runnable run object, then that Runnable object's run method is called; otherwise, this method does nothing and returns`.

Creating a `Thread` with the parameter-less constructor is not useful (since that thread will do nothing). However, if you create a sub-class of `Thread` that overrides the `run()` method, your sub-class's constructor can call `Thread`'s parameter-less constructor, so that constructor is still useful.

Comment: thanks ..but even if I try to start it(the non parameterized constructor) how will JVM know which run method to call..also in some other program when there are more than one thread running parallely it means both are executing,so which thread will be made to sleep by sleep method

Comment: @akshay The `t.sleep` statement appears in code that runs in the main thread. Therefore it will cause the main thread to sleep, regardless of how many threads are created/started.

Comment: so you mean that if I want another thread to sleep I should call it only inside the run method of that thread(or other functions called by run method)..also can u pls answer my another question regarding non parameterized constructor

Comment: @akshay Yes, that's what I meant. Which other question? Did you read my edited answer?

Comment: but even then when I extend threads class and write Thread t=new Thread(); how will thread know to call the overridden run method..am new to programming this might be a silly question:)

Comment: obviously you have to create an instance of your extended class then, not `new Thread()`.

Comment: @akshay when you extend Thread class you would write `Thread t=new ThreadSubClass()`, so `t.start()` would call the `run()` method of `ThreadSubClass`.

Comment: @Eran ohh k...u meant like that...yea then it is obvious...thanks